# Chartjs2 set data 0 to type doughnut

Tags: angular, chart.js

I have some datas for doughnut chart but at the beginning I want to show default doughnut chart and datas with 0 and equal size of parts.
I put `beginAtZero`

**JS**

```
scales: {
    yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
            beginAtZero: true,
        }
    }]
}
```

but value 0 of datas, chart is hidden I cant see any chart.But I need default equal size part of chart values with 0.
is it possible with doughnut chart?

Example:(but I want to make value 1 to 0,with 5 equal part)

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes!** It is possible.

To accomplish this, what you have to do is, generate the doughnut chart with...

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

as the **`data`** array, at the beginning.

Then, use the following tooltips callback function, to show the value **0** on tooltip.

```
options: {
   tooltips: {
      callbacks: {
         label: function(t, d) {
            var isSame = d.datasets[t.datasetIndex].data.every(function(e) {
               return e === 1;
            });
            if (isSame) return d.labels[t.index] + ': ' + 0;
            else return d.labels[t.index] + ': ' + d.datasets[t.datasetIndex].data[t.index];
         }
      }
   },
   ...
}
```

<sub>this will only show 0 on tooltip, if all the values of `data` array is 1</sub>

**ᴅᴇᴍᴏ ⧩**

```js
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
   type: 'doughnut',
   data: {
      labels: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May'],
      datasets: [{
         data: [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
         backgroundColor: [
            'rgba(0, 119, 204, 0.8)',
            'rgba(0, 119, 204, 0.7)',
            'rgba(0, 119, 204, 0.6)',
            'rgba(0, 119, 204, 0.4)',
            'rgba(0, 119, 204, 0.3)'
         ],
      }]
   },
   options: {
      responsive: false,
      legend: false,

      tooltips: {
         callbacks: {
            label: function(t, d) {
               var isSame = d.datasets[t.datasetIndex].data.every(function(e) {
                  return e === 1;
               });
               if (isSame) return d.labels[t.index] + ': ' + 0;
               else return d.labels[t.index] + ': ' + d.datasets[t.datasetIndex].data[t.index];
            }
         }
      }
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="ctx" height="200"></canvas>
```

**ꜰʏɪ :** you cannot create chart with all data as 0, to make 5 equal parts.

Comment: Yeap it worked thank you, can I ask how can I replace the datas with 0's. I have 5 variable like otherCounter,phoneCounter,pcCounter I want to display their number if initial is not 0. Thank you

Comment: uhm, that's a different question. you should rather **ask a new question** with adequate details, than asking it in the comment section :)